# Ubuntu 12.04 keeps booting to tty1

Tags: 12.04, boot, tty, xserver

I was trying to install xdmx & the last thing that I did was deleting the `~/.XAuthority*` files since I was getting error in locking authority file. On rebooting, I found myself on this screen.

I tried `startx` but I get errors. Here's the output:

```
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/ankesh/.Xauthority
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/ankesh/.Xauthority


X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux mindreader 3.11.0-20-generic #34~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 3 17:25:07 UTC 2014 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=a6d7d9bd-c1c4-4be9-96eb-8a54e6e71354 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 16 October 2013  04:41:23PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.14 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Apr 28 01:56:05 2014
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
xinit: server error
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/ankesh/.Xauthority
```

I also tried reinstalling Xorg but that didn't help either.

`echo $DISPLAY` gives nothing.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this. Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess - have you tried `touch /home/ankesh/.Xauthority`?

Comment: I did after you suggested but getting the same set of errors

Comment: As a quick fix re-installing X should do it, although there's likely an easier way.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Xorg but facing the same issue

Comment: Please provide the full output of `startx`.

Comment: @Danatela: Have updated the ques with full output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your GUI back, you need to restore Open-Source driver. To do this:

1. Remove `xorg.conf`:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
2. Uninstall NVidia

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   ```
3. Reboot and enjoy!

<sup>However, this is only workaround. Nouveau drivers are slow in 3D. I suggest you to wait new NVidia driver release and try it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For AMD the following in [the official BinaryDriverHowto/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) page solved the issue for me:

Remove/purge current fglrx and fglrx-amdcccle:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

To install the packages for hardware acceleration along with the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
```

Generate a fresh xorg.conf BEFORE REBOOTING!

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

There are some optional steps and multiple choices so make sure you check the 2.1. Installing via the command line section.